# how to improve the titan query performance when I have more than one conditions

Tags: titan, multiple-conditions

There is about 10,000,000 records in titan-0.5.4(storage backend is hbase and index with es), and I just want to find the vertex which within the specific circle and also has the label "shop". The query(query cost) runs about 1s，but getting the vertex(iterator cost) spend too much time. I wonder how does the titan deal with multiple conditions like the following:

```
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Iterator<Vertex> iterator = graph.query().has("geo",Geo.WITHIN, circle(40, 116, 15)).has("label","shop").vertices().iterator();

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("query cost(ms):" + (end - start));

    Set<Vertex> targetVertices = new HashSet<Vertex>();
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        targetVertices.add(iterator.next());
    }
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("iterator cost(ms):" + (end - start));
    System.out.println("vertices count): " + targetVertices.size());
```

Why it is so slowly and how can I improve the query performance?

Comment: If the `query cost(ms)` is 1 second, what is the `iteration cost(ms)` and `vertices count`?

Comment: Like the above code, I just can not get the result with a very long time(May be 20mins). But when I first just use the circle condition, and then use the iterator to filter the "shop" label. And the iterator cost about 80s and the circle condition get about 60000 vertices and valid vertices is 100. Does this prove that the label condition is not base on the circle condition?

Comment: Did you define an index that with the `geo` and `label` keys? Something like `mgmt.buildIndex('geoAndLabel',Vertex.class).addKey(geo).addKey(label).buildMixedIndex("search")` http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.4/indexes.html#index-mixed

Comment: Yes, I did. And without index there will print Warnings.

Answer (score 0):

among all vertices :

- if there are more vertices that may be in the circle than vertices that have label "shop" : you should put the "has shop" condition first.
- if there are more vertices that have label shop than vertices that may be in the circle : you still should put the "has shop" condition first.

The fewer points you check for being inside the circle, the faster it should be.

And for the speed of the query, I think that the query itself does not make the comparisons, it is more likely to be delayed until you try to access the results, that should explain time spent to get the iterator.

Comment: Thanks for response so quickly!  I also tried to put the "has shop" condition first,but has no effect. And I also doubt  that it does not execute the query until I try to access the result, but not sure it is correct.While I think it should not be so slowly.

Comment: maybe you should measure the same process with only the shop condition, and with only the circle condition, and see if one take much longer than the other.

Comment: Yes, I did. First, I just use the circle condition, and then use the iterator to filter the "shop" label. It seems a bit more faster, but not enough. I doubt the "has shop” condition is not based on the result of circle condition.

Comment: I almost have tried all ways I know, but has no effect.